# how mirror other port 6040 using 443 nginx?

Tags: nginx

I try to discover how I can use nginx to reply on 443 but using an app on port 6040, I need to nginx answer like 6040 app trought 443 ssl, anyone know how is possible do it?

Regars

Answer (score 1):

*I assume your app listeing for `http` requests on port 6040 is running on the same machine as your nginx server. If your app is listing for `https` requests on port 6040, see [nginx https upstreams](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-https-upstreams/) instead.*

---

**Create a server that listens on port 443 on your public ip and acts as a proxy for your internal app on port 6040.**

/etc/nginx/sites-available/www.example.com.vhost

```
server {
    # Listen on port 443 for both IPv4 and IPv6 and turn on http2 support.
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl on;
    # Paths to certificates assuming you're using let's encrypt / certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    # There's much more directives you should fine tune for https, but that's another task.

    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:6040;
        proxy_read_timeout      90;
        proxy_redirect          http://localhost:6040 https://www.example.com;
    }
}
```